# Are i.i.d. variables timing covariance to the -1/2 still i.i.d.?

Tags: probability

$x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ are i.i.d. random vectors.

$\Sigma = E[x_ix_i^T]$

So we denote $z_i = \Sigma^{-\frac{1}{2}}x_i$. Are $z_i, i= 0,1,2...n$ i.i.d.?

It seems i.i.d. to me since $Cov(z_i,z_j) = 0$. Is it correct?

Comment: Definition of $\Sigma$ a little confusing.  Is it supposed to be the sum over $i$?  However, in general lack of correlation does not necessarily mean independence.

Comment: I got it. Thanks.